# how to get value from h1 to select data using php

Tags: php, html

I want to print hello on h3 "winText" when lblAngka <= 100:

```
<div class="jumbotron" >
            <form name="form" action="" method="get">
            <h1 id="lblAngka" name="lblAngka">0</h1>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" id="btnBerhenti" disabled>Berhenti</button> 
            <h3 id="winText" disabled>sadasd<?php 
            if (isset($_GET['lblAngka'])){
                 if ($_GET['lblAngka'] <= 100)
                    echo "hello";
            }
            ?></h3>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to an integer:

```
if (intval($_GET['lbAngka']) <= 100)
```